# No toFloat in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wonder if there is a function that converts rational types to Float (Rational a => a -> Float).

I tried [hoogling](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Rational+a+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+Float), but found nothing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Haskell you don't convert *to* but *from*. See `fromRational`.

```
threeHalves :: Ratio Integer
threeHalves = 3 % 2
sqrt threeHalves -- Fails
sqrt $ fromRational threeHalves -- Succeeds
```

If you need a `Rational -> Float` function, you can define it as

```
toFloat x = fromRational x :: Float
```

Comment: Thanks, I especially like the first sentence.. should help a lot in the future.

Comment: Sometime you convert from, sometimes to.  There's, e.g., `toInteger`.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [fromIntegral](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afromIntegral) to convert `Int`s and `Integer`s to any instance of `Num`.

```
foo :: Float -> Float
foo x = x+1

value :: Int
value = 4

newValue = foo (fromIntegral value)
```

Answer (score 3):

[fromRational](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afromRational)?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Rational` is a type, not a typeclass, so `Rational a => a` doesn't make sense. Try hoogling [Rational -> Float](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Rational+-%3E+Float) instead.